# Create an ajax call

Tags: api, parse-platform

i've never used an ajax call,can anybody suggest me to create a jquery ajax call using this api (parse.com),what is H,G?:

```
         curl -X GET \
 -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: qS0KLMx5h9lFLGJIpj9qyhM9EEPiTS3VMk" \
 -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: nh3eoUo9GF2gMhcKJIfIt1Gm" \
 -G \
 --data-urlencode 'username=cooldude6' \
 --data-urlencode 'password=p_n7!-e8' \
 https://api.parse.com/1/login
```

Answer (score 0):

curl is a tool for sending HTTP requests. The -H flag sets a header and -G specifies that the data should be transmitted as a URL query parameter rather than content body. In this case, your command sends an HTTP GET command with the custom headers "X-Parse-Application-Id" and "X-Parse-REST-API-Key". This request was sent to https://api.parse.com/1/login?username=cooldude6&password=p_n7!-e8.

You don't need to become a CURL expert to use Parse; the REST API helps you understand how the Parse API works across the wire, but there are both first and third party APIs for just about every language you would need.

P.S. The Parse docs page helps you by pre-filling the value of X-Parse-Application-Id and X-Parse-REST-API-Key with keys *from your actual app*. By posting these keys online, others can write code that will look like your app to Parse. Though best practices would suggest you secure your app so that it's OK for these keys to leak (e.g. by setting class-level permissions), you may consider deleting & recreating a new app since it sounds like you are just starting development.

Comment: The equivalent in JavaScript is the XMLHttpRequest, most commonly used with $.ajax()